# Exception #0 (LogicException): Unable to load theme by specified key: '12'

Tags: magento2, theme-fallback, custom-theme

it's occurred when I tried to change theme from back-end from custom theme to Luma theme.

> Unable to load theme by specified key: '12'
>   [image]

**I tried:**

- check table `core_config_data` for theme entry and check by changing it.

`SELECT * FROM`core_config_data`WHERE`path`LIKE '%theme_id%'` it show two entry with different scope one if have scope default and other one is store having id 6 so I delete it.

- check table `theme` for theme id. no luck theme have different id & even i check it by changing id of custom theme after I delete entry and deploy theme.
- match both table(`theme` and `core_config_data` ) entry in db.

**deleted custom theme completely**

- delete all db entry for product & category assign theme.

`SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = "custom_theme"`

`SELECT * from catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = product custom design attribute id ;`

`SELECT * from catalog_category_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = category custom design attribute id ;`

I delete all entry for categories & products assign theme.

it's now saving luma theme in back-end but showing error 
[image]

to try to solve this issues now it's only luma & blank theme.
[image]

I can't find any theme having id 12   entry  in db. in following tables `theme`, `core_config_data`

Comment: You need to do indexing   from  command line

Comment: Also do the proper cache  flush...

Comment: @AmitBera  Thanks  I got it homepage assign in cms_page table with following id(12) I change it to my theme id ..

Comment: @AmitBera  I tried to flush cache also reindex but still error. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homepage is assigned to my custom theme whose id is 12. I deleted it  so I got this by checking `cms_page` table.

- It's common to have such problem when you working with custom themes and delete theme.
- **My Suggestion** Please check `theme`,`core_config_data` table for theme entry and `eav_attribute`,`catalog_product_entity_varchar`,`catalog_category_entity_varchar`,`cms_page`,`design_change` for assign theme to products,categories,cms pages, custom design.

[image]

Comment: in 2024 this happened to me when i deleted an old theme and applied a new one. so i went to cms_page like mentioned above and changed my homepage value to null and it detected my new theme.